# Who poisoned Brock in Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad

It's very un-certain in S04E12 (End Time) who poisoned Brock. Was it Walt or Gus who poisoned him? How was he even poisoned?

- If Gus poisoned Brock then he'd get Jesse to kill Walt.
- If Walt poisoned Brock then he'd get Jesse to turn against Gus.

Comment: Mmm - its not exactly a word for word duplicate, but it is essentially, as other questions make it entirely clear that Walt did it.

Comment: @iandotkelly yeah, I noticed them.

Comment: If you think I've been unfair marking this as a duplicate let me know.  However in the absence of on-screen evidence, the show-runner Vince Gilligan's word seems pretty definitive.

Comment: @iandotkelly no I don't think you've been unfair. :)